# "How can I create a subfolder for Google Form images using a Python script in Google Drive?"

Tags: python, forms, directory, google-drive-api

The images uploaded to the Google Form are placed in a folder on Google Drive.
I would like a Python code that separates these images into separate subfolders for each submitted form. Optionally, the name of the folder could be determined based on the answer to the "Name" question in the form for identification.
So far, I have tried this unsuccessfully:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '' 
DRIVE_FOLDER_ID = ''
SAVE_FOLDER = ''

def create_drive_service():
    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    return build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

def create_folder(service, name, parent_id=None):
    file_metadata = {
        'name': name,
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    }
    if parent_id:
        file_metadata['parents'] = [parent_id]
    folder = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields='id').execute()
    return folder.get('id')

def download_images(service, folder_id, save_folder):
    query = f"'{folder_id}' in parents"
    results = service.files().list(q=query).execute()
    files = results.get('files', [])

    if not os.path.exists(save_folder):
        os.makedirs(save_folder)

    for file in files:
        file_id = file['id']
        file_name = file['name']
        request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
        fh = open(os.path.join(save_folder, file_name), 'wb')
        media_request = request
        media_download = media_request.execute()
        fh.write(media_download)
        fh.close()

def main():
    service = create_drive_service()
    folder_id = create_folder(service, SAVE_FOLDER, parent_id=DRIVE_FOLDER_ID)
    download_images(service, folder_id, SAVE_FOLDER)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I might have attempted the API settings incorrectly as well.